# Extending RouteDefinition and RestDefinition in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I wanted to add an extra method in camel **RouteDefinition** and **RestDefinition** for that I extended all the necessary classes and rewritten **CustomRouteDefinition,CustomRestDefinition,CustomRoutesDefinition,CustomRestsDefinition and CustomRouteBuilder** and  I have  overriden all the DSL methods.

Now, I have migrated to Camel Version 2.16.0 which has new DSL methods implemented on it and I want to use these latest version because it has swagger java library in it.Do i need to again override/re-write these classes or is there anyway to avoid this?

And What is the significance of the Method ***addRouteDefinition*** in CamelContext.Can it help me in anyway for solving the above issue?

Comment: dont override them, but use the as-is out of the box. you dont want to maintain your own code of all that - its not intension of camel end users to do so.

Comment: But I want to add few extra  DSL Methods .How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Replying to an old topic, but I faced this thread searching for the same subject.
I was looking to have a fluent way to enhance Java DSL but it is not possible. I came up with a new builder, and new domain definition class that encapsulates the real RouteBuilder. With this approach I was able to extend Java DSL to my purpose, but kind of limited even though.
https://github.com/rjmveloso/apache-camel-extensions/blob/feature/route-doc/camel-route-doc/src/main/java/io/github/apache/camel/model/DocumentedRouteBuilder.java